# Silly problem: font in y labels do not change

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I never encountered these problems, in a plot I am able to set the font size and family of labels in the x-axis. With the same command I am able to set the size of the font of labels in the y-axis but not the family. Also commands "bar width=" and "column sep=" are not obeyed, I am not able to change neither the width nor the interbar separation.
I have compiled with LaTeX and XeLaTeX.
My code is

```
\documentclass[border=0pt, preview]{standalone}
\usepackage[usernames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
%\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
bar width=0.2cm,
column sep=0.3cm,
axis line style={Gray},
ybar stacked,
bar width=4pt,
enlargelimits=0.02,
axis on top,
title={\sffamily Data},
symbolic x coords={19, 20},
xtick={19, 20},
ytick={0, 50, 100, 150,200},
xticklabel style={font=\small\sffamily, rotate=90},
yticklabel style={font=\small\sffamily},
ymajorgrids]
\addplot+[ybar, color=Green] plot
coordinates {(19,157.4)
(20,110)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your issue with `bar width=` is easily explained by the fact you define it twice and only the second one (4pt) seems to be executed just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Is this more what you are looking for? The issue with using `\sffamily` is basically that the ticks are in math-mode, so you may want to use `\sansmath` instead. And as mentioned in the comment above, if you define the `bar width` only once, it works just fine.

```
\documentclass[border=5pt, preview]{standalone}
\usepackage[usernames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\usepackage{sansmath}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            width=5cm,
            bar width=0.2cm,
            axis line style={Gray},
            ybar stacked,
            axis on top,
            title={\sffamily Data},
            xmin=18.5,xmax=20.5,
            xtick distance =1,
            ymin=0,ymax=200,
            xticklabel style={font=\small\sansmath,rotate=90}, 
            yticklabel style={font=\small\sansmath},  
            ymajorgrids]
            \addplot+[ybar, color=Green] coordinates {(19,157.4) (20,110)};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Not sure about the `column sep` though.

[image]

Comment: Thank you Markus, something happens with my code, in the one I sent I had defined the fonts in the labels at both axes as font=\small\sffamily; the labels in the x-axis were sans serif, in the y-axis they did not change (they had serifs), even so if I changed the size of the font the sizes changed in both axes. Now I am using \sansmath instead of \sffamily and now the labels in the y-axis are sans serif but the labels in the x-axis have serifs. I will review the code and my data to see if I find something that could explain this. Thanks again and I will let you know.